# How to analyze and get the main context from email subject in python

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I have started learning Ai . I want to solve a problem but don,t know which topics or content should i read to solve this problem
The problem is I want to get the main context from email subject

Examples of subjects lines are

```
My password is incorrect please solve my problem
please issue my funds
please issue my salary slip
please add this stock into inventory
Error is show in main page application
.
.
.
```

What i want to get in results
Example from given subject lines a have software which have finance department , inventory management department , technical team to resolve bugs .
I want to analyze the subject lines and then i want to analyze from which department i should send this email.
Can you show me a roadmap to solve this problem.

Comment: It would be easier to create a template or form other people can use, than creating an ML/AI model, that can reliably do this job.

Comment: @RIJIK As you wish if you want to create a form or a template then i a m happy for you but i will be reliable on ML/AI model because i have started learning AI

Comment: Shooting with cannons at sparrows eh?

If you want to learn ML/AI I suggest starting out with text classification. For example take a look at simple methods like [Naive Bayes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2L2Uv9pdDA). Do you have large amounts of training data? If yes, then take a look at Neural Networks. Once you are comfortable with them move on to transformer models and language models. Then you will be at the state of the art.

Comment: @RIJIK You could suggest me these topics to learn before.

Answer (score 0):

Your main goal is to classify text (i.e., email subjects) into one or more predefined class, depending on your design (you could always choose only one department to forward the email to, or multiple if the issue is inter-disciplinary). I would suggest to first go through some tutorials on supervised learning and multi-class classification. In my experience, they usually start with images, but the underlying logic is still the same. Once you understand the main concepts, you can look into natural language processing and text classification. Also, this sounds like a relatively general problem, so you should also be able to find some pretrained models or even full solutions online.